# How to use map(ES6) to return a list of functions?(ES6)

Tags: ecmascript-6

How can I use map to return this output

```html
get funcone() { return this.Form.get(funcone"); }
get functwo() { return this.Form.get("functwo"); }
get functhree() { return this.Form.get("functhree"); }
get funcfour() { return this.Form.get("funcfour"); }
```

I used this array

```html
FormValues=['funcone','functwo','functhree','funcfour'];
```

And this map

```html
FormValues.map(Value=>{
    get Value() { return this.Form.get(Value); }
 })
```

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you want to define those functions as getters on some object, or class. Let's assume it's a class.

That syntax can't work - it creates a `Value` getter, rather than `funcone` getter. Now, while you *can* define a getter using a variable for the getter's name:

```
let propName = "foo";
class Foo {
  get [propName]() { return "You're getting a foo"; }
}
new Foo().foo
// => "You're getting a foo"
```

as far as I know, there's no way to make a loop inside the `class` declaration, nor a way to keep reopening a class and adding new stuff to it like in Ruby, so `class` definition inside a loop also won't work.

However, `class` syntax is just a sugar for the older prototypal inheritance, so everything we can do with the class syntax, we can also do without it (though vice versa does not hold). In order to add new stuff to the class, we just need to stick it to the class's prototype object. We can explicitly define a getter method using `Object.defineProperty`.

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.Form = {
      one: 1,
      two: 2,
      three: 3,
      four: 4
    }
  }
}

let props = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
props.forEach(propName =>
  Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype, propName, {
    get: function() { return this.Form[propName]; }
  })
);

new Foo().three
// => 3
```

It would be almost the same code to give the getters to an object rather than a class; you'd just be defining properties on the object itself, rather than on a prototype.